# Subir proyecto a github

Tags: git, github

Me salta un error al hacer un git init > git add 'nombre carpeta' > git commmit > git push origin master

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que tus archivos locales están desactualizados, a que me  refiero, que en Github tienes cambios que en tu computadora no.

Puedes usar el comando `git pull origin master` para actualizar tus archivos locales.

Entre al [repositorio](https://github.com/nauumb/PRO), ahí tienes un archivo README.md, estas seguro que lo tienes en tu computadora?

Comment: No tengo ese archivo README.md en mi portátil ¿he de tener todos los datos que se encuentran en el repositorio en el portátil para poder realizar el push?

Comment: @nauumb En este caso si, porque si no los toma como que tus archivos en la computadora están desactualizados

Comment: @nauumb No respondas tu propia pregunta, mejor usa comentarios. Ahora, volviendo con ese error que te da con ```git pull```, ahora intenta ```git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories```